# xsl:for-each to select unique cases

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am transforming XML to PDF using xslt 1.0. I have to select all the unique memberId covering given condition "IsBeneficialOwner=false" .

```
<xsl:for-each select="//clientMembers/memberId" >
  <xsl:if test="not(contains(/clientMemberRelations[IsBeneficialOwner='true']/memberId))" >
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="white">
        <fo:block white-space-treatment="preserve"
          ><xsl:value-of select="//clientMembers/memberId"
          /><fo:leader/></fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="white">
        <fo:block white-space-treatment="preserve"
          ><xsl:value-of select="//clientMembers/name/name"
          /><fo:leader/></fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="white">
        <fo:block white-space-treatment="preserve"
          ><xsl:value-of select="//clientMembers/type/memberType"
          /><fo:leader/></fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="white">
        <fo:block white-space-treatment="preserve"
          ><xsl:value-of select="//clientMemberRelations/association/associationToEntity"
          /><fo:leader/></fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>                    
    </fo:table-row>     
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

What is wrong in the above not contains condition? I am getting the below error in my console -

> javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: FuncContains only allows 2 arguments

Sample XML File is below -

```
    <clientMemberRelations>
        <updateSource>xxxxx</updateSource>
        <ownedEntityMemberId>2</ownedEntityMemberId>
        <association>               
            <associationToEntity>Controlling Person </associationToEntity>
        </association>
        <IsBeneficialOwner>true</IsBeneficialOwner>
        <memberId>6</memberId>
    </clientMemberRelations>
     <clientMemberRelations>
        <updateSource>xxxxx</updateSource>
        <ownedEntityMemberId>2</ownedEntityMemberId>
        <association>               
            <associationToEntity>Controlling Person </associationToEntity>
        </association>
        <IsBeneficialOwner>false</IsBeneficialOwner>
        <memberId>4</memberId>
    </clientMemberRelations>
    <clientMembers>
        <address>
            <proofSourceDmcId>0</proofSourceDmcId>
            <postalZipCode>0-0</postalZipCode>
            <updateSource>xxx</updateSource>
            <city>xxx</city>
            <proofSourceDmcVersion>0</proofSourceDmcVersion>
            <stateProvince>xxx</stateProvince>
            <Country>xxxxx</Country>
            <type>xx</type>
            <line1>xxxx</line1>
            <ISOCountry>xxx</ISOCountry>
        </address>          
        <memberId>4</memberId>
    </clientMembers>
```

As you can see XML has 2 nodes clientMemberRelations and clientMembers. 
I have to pick all the memberId coming in the clientMembers Nodes, but I have to leave out those memberIds where the "IsBeneficialOwner" flag "true". 
I have tried several combinations of xsl:for-each and xsl:variable but not getting the desired result .

Please suggest if the desired is possible is XSLT 1.0 and how ?

Comment: It be better to show your input XML, and the output you expect, as the answer to your current question is that " `contains` takes two arguments, both strings, whereas you are providing one argument of a node set". To give you an answer that actually solves your problem, showing the XML would help alot. Thank you!

Comment: Apologies, added the sample XML above.

Comment: Please include the root tag of XML especially if it contains namespaces. Right now this post is not well-formed.

Comment: Also, *clientMemberRelations* is not a parent but a sibling of *clientMembers*. And where are `clientMembers/name/name` or `clientMembers/type/memberType` paths? We need **full** reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you are concerned about is

```
not(contains(/clientMemberRelations[IsBeneficialOwner='true']/memberId))
```

It may be easier to see the problem if you break it into multiple lines (this is syntactically correct XPath, though one might not know it from looking at examples on the web).

```
not(
  contains(
    /clientMemberRelations[IsBeneficialOwner='true']/memberId
   )
)
```

Do you see the problem now?  The `not` function should take one argument, and gets one argument here.  The `contains` function requires two arguments (that's what your error message is saying, though 'FuncContains' is perhaps not the most obvious way to refer to the `contains()` function of XPath), but you are giving it only one.

From the fragment you give, it seems likely that you wish to emit a table row either if the member ID in question contains some magic substring, or if the member ID is contained in some string which contains a list of all the member IDs for which you want to generate rows in the table.  In the first case, you want something like

```
not(contains(
    /clientMemberRelations[IsBeneficialOwner='true']/memberId,
    $magic-string
   )
)
```

In the second case, you want something like

```
not(contains(
    $wanted-list,
    /clientMemberRelations[IsBeneficialOwner='true']/memberId
   )
)
```

That's the answer to the question you asked.

On the other hand, your prose description of the problem suggests something entirely different, which would require a different fix.  The only thing the two analyses have in common is that you appear in need of a better understanding of what the `contains()` function does (and that you should work a bit on knowing what question you want to ask and asking that question).

You say

> I have to select all the unique memberId covering given condition "IsBeneficialOwner=false" .

I think you mean that for each `memberId` element in the for-each loop, you want to check to see whether that member ID appears as the value of an element in the set `/clientMemberRelations [IsBeneficialOwner='true'] /memberId`.  The simplest way to do that is to formulate your for-each loop something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//clientMembers/memberId" >
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=". = /clientMemberRelations
                        [IsBeneficialOwner='true'] 
                        /memberId">
      <!--* it's a beneficial owner, no output here! *-->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test=". = /clientMemberRelations
                        [IsBeneficialOwner='false']
                        /memberId">
      <!--* it's not a beneficial owner, write a row! *-->
      <fo:table-row>
        ...
      </
    </
    <xsl:when test=". = /clientMemberRelations
                        [IsBeneficialOwner]
                        /memberId>
      ... handle the case where there is an `IsBeneficialOwner`
          element but it's neither true nor false ... 
    </
    <xsl:when test=". = /clientMemberRelations
                        [not(IsBeneficialOwner)]
                        /memberId>
      ... handle the case where there is no `IsBeneficialOwner`
          element as sibling of the memberId ... 
          and also the case where there is no such element ...
    </
    <xsl:otherwise>
      ... handle any remaining cases ...  
    </
  </
</
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Michael Sperberg-McQueen's comments, I would simply note that

```
<xsl:for-each select="//clientMembers/memberId" >
  <xsl:if test="not(contains(/clientMemberRelations[IsBeneficialOwner='true']/memberId))" >
```

Looks wrong because the test expression is going to have the same value for every node selected by the `xsl:for-each`. I think you almost certainly want an expression in the `test` attribute that gives a different result depending on what the context item is, and this expression doesn't.

Comment: Michael , this was my attempt to create the expression. I am still a newbie to xslt learning as I go, hence my request for help :-) . Please suggest what would be the correct expression - again " my intention is to pick all the memberId where the "beneficialOwner" tag is missing or "beneficialOwner" is false.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not interested in writing XSLT 1.0 code - it's nearly 20 years old, and is just too much like hard work. You appear to be using Java, so there's no reason not to move to XSLT 2.0 or 3.0. And it would be much easier to help you if you simplified the problem down to its essence - I really don't want to have to wade through 40 different elements to find the two that are actually relevant to the problem.